# Check if passed argument is file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I wanted to get into the directory which is starts with DL and go to INBOUND directory then Check if directory having files or directory.If files then count the no of files and write it into IWCO.txt  file along with  directory name. If directory then get in to all  the directory count no of files in  it then write it into a IWCO.txt file along with directory name.

for ex:

```
DL_ComedyCentralRecords/INBOUND/Chris Hardwick FUNCOMFORTABLE/abc.txt
DL_Paracadute/INBOUND/acb.txt def.txt
```

i want output  like

```
DL_ComedyCentralRecords/INBOUND/Chris Hardwick FUNCOMFORTABLE|1
DL_Paracadute/INBOUND|2
```

Answer (score 2):

`[ -f "$filename" ]` is true for files,

`[ -d "$dirname" ]` is true for directories.

```
if [ -d "$filename" ] ; 
   then echo "$filename"/ ; 
elif [ -f "$filename" ] ; 
   then echo "$filename"'*' ; 
fi
```

Comment: There are many more [test operators](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) that OP may find useful as well.